# Richt text change default configuration

Tags: control-panel, redactor

Is it possible to change the default settings of the Rich text field? I know that I can change the configuration in `Simple.json` and `Standard.json` but I can't find a `Default.json` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "Default" is Craft's default configuration and is not user configurable.